# Is it bad to leave graphical applications open on Windows Server?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Can leaving graphical applications open in Windows Server negatively affect performance after you close your RDP session?

Sometimes I RDP into a Windows Server to discover that Task Manager or Computer Management are still open from my last RDP session.
Does this mean that these applications have been consuming resources even while I was logged off?

Does Windows Server have a way to detect when the graphical applications are not being used and free up the resources needed to run the graphical portion of the app?

Comment: Note that neither Task Manager nor Computer Management use much in the way of resources anyway.  Unless the server is already struggling, it isn't going to make any difference.  I suppose if you leave them running 24/7 the increased power usage might add up over time, but it's never going to be much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean that these applications have been consuming resources
>   even while I was logged off?

If they're still running then you haven't logged off of the session, you've disconnected from the session, and yes they continue to consume resources.

> Does Windows Server have a way to detect when the graphical
>   applications are not being used and free up the resources needed to
>   run the graphical portion of the app?

No.

> Is it bad to leave graphical applications open on Windows Server?

Is your server experiencing resource contention or performance issues? If so then yes, it's bad. If not, then no. Leaving a disconnected session running may be bad for other reasons (security), but that's up to you to determine.

Comment: So does this mean it can be preferable (from a security & performance perspective) to **sign out** rather than simply closing the RDP session?

Comment: That's a bit subjective, but generally yes it's preferable to log out of the session.

Comment: Personally, I consider it to be incredibly bad practice to leave a disconnected session running instead of logging out and I get quite irritated with my colleagues for not logging out of their sessions.

Comment: I don't see any security implications, can you expand on that?  (Oh, I suppose perhaps if you've got a web browser open to an external site or something silly like that, but not in the more typical case like the one the OP describes.)

Comment: Credential-less session hijacking comes to mind. Lateral movement from a hijacked session would be trivial. The myriad ways a hijacker could do damage are beyond my limited brain and experience but I don't leave that to chance by leaving disconnected sessions "laying" around.

Answer (score 1):

> Does Windows Server have a way to detect when the graphical applications are not being used and free up the resources needed

Ideally you shouldn't be logging in at all, and just using remote tools and powershell.  But if that isn't an option in your environment, then consider setting a policy to disconnect/reset RDP sessions automatically.

The policy settings are under.

> Computer Configuration / Administrative Templates / Windows Components / Remote Desktop Services / Remote Desktop Session Host / Session Time Limits

But that being said, leaving task manager or an MMC open in a disconnected session really isn't going to make much of difference on a typical server.  Unless your system is seriously resource starved.

Comment: Also, it depends on what you are running i.e. what's the purpose of the server. For general administrative tasks on a Windows Server it's better to logoff when you're finished, but if there's something you must look regularly or e.g. some GUI that consumes much disk I/O during its startup, it might be better to avoid closing it. But, just like Zoredache says here, such GUI should be separated from the backend server and run on a client computer, instead.